# comment_admin_overview is missing

Tags: theming

I am working on hook_theme_registry_alter. I have tried to dpm($theme_registry). But comment_admin_overview is missing, The version of drupal is 7. Any ideas??.

```
function hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  dpm($theme_registry);
  $theme_registry['comment_admin_overview']['function'] = 'theme_hook_comment_admin_overview';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`comment_admin_overview()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.admin.inc/function/comment_admin_overview/7) is a form function in Drupal 7 (it was a theme function in 4, 5 & 6).

You can use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to make your changes instead.

Comment: Hi Clive, I wish to theme the entire comment listing, so it would be better to use hook_form_alter. rt?

Comment: You can theme the comment specifically by overriding comment.tpl.php in your theme (or via `hook_registry_alter()` in a module like you're already trying), but the form needs to be themed as a separate 'thing', as it's built differently and only included in the comment, rather than built as a part of it

Comment: One more question. What I am trying to do is exactly adding few more operation to VBO and listing the comments along with a collapsible form to edit the same with pre filled value in hook_form_formID_alter. Is there any thing wrong doing this way. I have a drupal 6 module which I'm trying to convert it into drupal 7. In form_alter, I'm checking the form id and assigning the #submit a particular function.